# Внедрение кода в метод из строки

Tags: java, рефлексия

Подскажите, как можно внедрить код (считанный из строки) в нужный мне метод.
Создал Proxy объект, но дальше затык, заранее спасибо!

```
    private Object getProxyObject(String textMethod) {
    final MyClassLoader classLoader = new MyClassLoader();
    Class[] interfaces = {Worker.class};
    InvocationHandler myHandler = new InvocationHandler() {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            //Строка с новым кодом для метода, должна внедряться тут? textMethod
            //method.invoke(someClass,args);
            return null;
        }
    };
    return Proxy.newProxyInstance(classLoader,interfaces,myHandler);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Мне, кажется надо поискать библиотеки типа [Spoon](http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/). Там есть раздел "Code Transformation", который должен Вам помочь.

Еще есть [JavaPoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet) Нашел по нему [легкое введение](https://www.codeflow.site/ru/article/java-poet). Надеюсь поможет.